# How to run cmd as admin and run commands together

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, admin

I'm looking for a way to be able to open a admin level cmd prompt and then execute a command in that same admin cmd all together in a batch file.

I was trying to fiddle around with:

- powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"

To do this, but I couldn't figure out a way to send a command to the newly created admin cmd.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right path, all you needed was the argument `-ArgumentList`

Example:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c echo test && pause'"
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks for your help!